# confusion with bitfield in C

Tags: c, bit-fields

In the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct
{
  int Member1 : 3;
  int Member2 : 1;
}d2;

int main(){

  d2.Member1 = 7;
  printf("%d\n",d2.Member1);

  return 0;

}
```

The result is `-1`, why is it? What's the binary value of the `d2` now?

Comment: the most significant bit of an int is the sign bit, try unsigned

Comment: Use `unsigned int` instead of `int`.

Comment: @lurker: The `printf` format specifier has no effect on the conversion (which is performed before call to `printf`). The bit-field value will be promoted to `int` regardless of what format specifier is used and what type the bit-field itself has.

Comment: @AndreyT whoops, yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C language does not define whether an `int` bit-field is signed or unsigned. The decision is left to implementation. For this reason, it is typically not a good idea to ever declare `int` bit-fields. Use either explicitly `signed int` or explicitly `unsigned int` bit-fields, depending on what you need. (It is one area of C language where `int` *does not* necessarily mean `signed int`.)

In your case your 3-bit `int` bit-field happened to be signed. The value range of such bit-field is `[-4, 3]`, assuming 2's-complement representation. You attempted to assign `7` to it, causing overflow. What happens in case of signed integer overflow on assignment is implementation-defined. You ended up with `-1` apparently.

Answer (score 4):

Because you did not specify if `d2.Member1` is signed or unsigned, it is up to the compiler and apparently the one you are using chose to make it a signed field, and therefore has the range -4 to 3.  7 is out of range, so it overflows.

Make `d2.Member1` an `unsigned int` instead, and use `%u` in your `printf()` call instead of `%d`. ([Demo](http://ideone.com/akM5aW).)

Comment: nit pick, but I wouldn't call it overflow if an operation didn't occur, but that's right.

Comment: `u` conversion specifier requires an `unsigned int` so you need to cast the argument to `unsigned int` here. Moreover it is implementation defined if `d2.Member1` is a signed or an unsigned bit-field.

Comment: @kenny Technically assignment is an operation, no?

Comment: @cdhowie: A bit-field wiuth value range that fits into `int` will be promoted to `int`, even if the original bit-field type is `unsigned int`. For this reason, `%d` in `printf` is actually more appropriate in this case. To use `%u` one'd have to explicitly cast the argument, e.g. `(unsigned) d2.Member1`.

Comment: regardless of what you decide to call it, assigning an out-of-range value to a signed integral type causes implementation-defined behaviour (which may raise a signal). So your compiler should document what happens here, although good luck in finding that documentation!

Comment: Hi, I understand that it is signed, but I don't understand why it becomes -1. The binary value of signed -1 is 1111, and 7 is 111, and there are only 3 bits to be used, how it became -1?

Comment: @user3289218 for a 3 bit int number 111 is -1, in your example 1111 it would be a 4 bit field.

Comment: @user3289218: `-1` is `1111`? Where did `1111` come from? Why not `11111` or `111111`?

Answer (score 1):

You assign binary 111 to 3-bit value. Since you declared the field as signed, this means 3-bit long '-1'. When you request an integer value, it is left-padded with the leftmost bit to preserve the sign.
If you expect the output 7, declare your bit field as `unsigned Member1: 3`. Expansion to full integer will pad the missing MSB with 0 rather than the leftmost bit.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the C90 standard:

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of one of **`int`**, **`unsigned int`**, or **`signed int`**. Whether the high-order bit position of a (possibly qualified) “plain” **`int`** bit-field is treated as a sign bit is implementation-defined. A bit-field is interpreted as an integral type consisting of the specified number of bits.

So it's `-1` because you didn't explicitly specify it as unsigned and, in the C implementation you're using, the high-order bit position of a "plain" `int` bit-field is treated as a sign bit.  You have a 3-bit bit-field, all the bits of which are 1, so that's -1.